# Significant figures and precision

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

Which of these two measurements is more precise, 5.1 cm or 0.002 ? As per concept of significant figures 5.1 cm is more precise because it has two signicant figures while the other oone has just one

Comment: Are you asking or telling?  It's not clear if this is a question or an answer to something else.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Comment: brick 9 , I am asking which of those two measurements is more precise?

Comment: The former is more precise relatively, the latter absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring in thousandths of a centimeter is more precise than measuring in tenths of a centimeter. As far as significance goes, 0.001 is the same as .001 or 00.001, or 000.001, so it has three significant figures however it is written, changing or omitting any of the significant figures would change the measurement. The same with 5.1, or 05.1, or 005.1, which has two significant figures. For a more complete definition of significant figures see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: 0.001 cm has only one significant digit

Comment: @Arun Arora: ok, do away with all of what you think are not significant digits and see if it means the same thing

Comment: In my opinion, 0.002 cm is clearly more precise. But i have studied that the more the significant figures the more precise measurement is. In above case 5.1 cm has more significant figures than 0.002 cm, so it is contrary to what it seems (i.e. 0.002 is more precise). Pls help me out here. I think I am missing something.

Comment: @ArunArora: just because it is a 0 does not mean it is not significant, 0.002 has 1 digit that is not significant, the first 0, removing it does  not change the number, it is still two thousandths, Now delete all zeros, is .2 still two thousandths, or does it now mean two tenths?